# How to get access scoped-model models

Tags: dart, flutter, scoped-model

I am trying to get access to my models at _buildProductCard widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<ConnectedProductModel>(
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, Widget child, ConnectedProductModel model) {
        return Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(),
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => model.addProduct('NaNa',
                      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/01/27/22/31/girl-3959203__340.jpg'),
                  child: Text('Add Product'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  //build the cards
                  itemBuilder: _buildProductCard,
                  //lengta of the list,
                  itemCount: model.product.length,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProductCard(BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Card(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(model.product[index].image),
            Text(model.product[index].address),
            ButtonBar(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.blue, size: 40.0),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ProductNavigation()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.blue, size: 40.0),
                  onPressed: () => model.deleteProduct(index),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.info, color: Colors.blue, size: 40.0),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ProductInfoPage(
                            model.product[index].address,
                            model.product[index].image,
                            model.product[index].id),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon:
                      Icon(Icons.contact_mail, color: Colors.blue, size: 40.0),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FormPage()),
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
```

As you see, i wrapped my scaffold with ScopedModelDescendant, but i can't get access to my models inside _buildProductCard method.
If i wrapped my_buildProductCard with  ScopedModelDescendant i of course can get access, but it make the function work very slow cause it just build it twice, and i sure there is a better way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your *item builder* you can do as follow:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return _buildProductCard(context, index, model);
              })
```

And in you *_buildProductCard* add an extra parameter **ConnectedProductModel model**. So signature will be `Widget _buildProductCard(BuildContext context, int index, ConnectedProductModel model)`

Just don't forget the **return** inside itemBuilder. 
Hope this help.